# How to build a temp structt variable in s-function builder?

Tags: matlab, function, simulink

I meet a problem in the s function builder, I have to use a temp structure variable to transport the inputs to the extended C function.

Background: csolve function is a quadratic programming solver generated by CVXGEN for my QP problem, and I have tested the function in level-2 matlab s-fun. Now I want to use s function builder to genetate the TLC file that support the embedded code generate.

My Problem: 
1) I have to use a temp structure variable 'params' to the inputs to csolve function in the outputs panel, could you please help me to solve this problem? 
2) I find that in cvxgen folder contains a header file contains 'tic' and 'toc' function, how to use these functions in s function builder?

```
params.Aeq=Aeq;
params.beq=beq;
params.Aineq=Aineq;
params.bineq=bineq;
params.Smat=Smat;
params.Wmat=Wmat;
params.alpha=alpha;

[vars, status] = csolve(params)

y0=vars.x;
converge=status.converge;
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

for the attached files please see [here](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/answers/467582-how-to-add-a-temp-struct-variable-in-s-function-builder?s_tid=prof_contriblnk)

Comment: I was working with Matlab long time ago (~ 10 years); therefore my comment may be wrong: Calling a `mex` file (S-function or C-written Matlab function) from another `mex` file is not that easy! It would be easier to modify the file `csolve.c` in a way that you rename the function `mexFunction()` and pass C data types (such as structures) to the function instead of `mxArray` pointers that represent Matlab data types.

Comment: I also removed the tags `builder` and `s` from your question because these two tags have a different meaning: The tag `s` is intended for a statistics programming language named "S", not for "S-functions".

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply, I have no experience in writing the structure varible in C language, however, the C function csolve.c needs a structure parameter to transport the S-function inputs. For simulation purpose, I have tested the C function (mex file) in level-2 matlab s-function. But for code generation, I need the S-function builder to generate a TLC file that needed in simulink coder or embedded coder.

Answer (score 0):

First some background information that you should know:

Matlab and C work completely differently and use different kinds of data types. To call C code from Matlab, so called "mex-functions" are generated. Matlab uses a special data type named `mxArray` to exchange data between Matlab and these "mex-functions", which are written in C.

In the C program an element (for example a variable) of the type `mxArray` represents a Matlab value of any data type. Matlab provides some functions (like `mxGetData()`) to access the actual data of the Matlab data element from the C function: There is some function for checking if the `mxArray` represents a floating-point value or a string. Another function allows you to convert the value from `mxArray` to `double` if the element has a floating-point value.

> ```
> [vars, status] = csolve(params)
> ```

This means you want to call a "mex-function" from an "S-function".

Theoretically, this is possible but it is not as easy as you think:

First of all, the entry point of both types of functions is named `mexFunction()` in the C code. This means you cannot simply combine the C codes of both functions because in this case you would have two functions with the same name (`mexFunction`) in your S-function.

You might call the function `mexCallMATLAB`; however Mathworks writes that this function should not be called from S-functions.

The other possibility would be loading the mex-function using DLL functions (in Windows: `LoadLibrary`, `GetProcAddress`, `FreeLibrary`) and call the function `mexFunction()` of the mex-function using a function pointer.

However, in this case you have to convert all C data types to `mxArray` data and the data returned from the mex-function must be converted back ...

> ... a TLC file that is needed in ... embedded coder

The functions that access data of the `mxArray` type are only available when Matlab is running.

If you generate code that shall be executable outside Matlab, you cannot use `mxArray` and therefore you cannot call mex-functions.

The file `csolve.c` defines four structure variables:

```
Vars vars;
Params params;
Workspace work;
Settings settings;
```

And what the file actually does is the following:

- Read the structure `params` (`mxArray` data type), convert these content to C data types and write the data into the four structure variables above
- Call the following code:

  ```
  steps = solve();
  for (i = 0; i < extra_solves; i++)
      solve();
  ```

  The function `solve()` is defined in the other `.c` files in the project.
- Take the values from the four structure variables and the value `step` returned by `solve()` and convert the data to `mxArray`.
- Return the result as `[vars, status]`

You can define the four variables in your S-function code, fill these structures the same way the file `csolve.c` does it, call the `solve()` function as it is shown above and read the data of `vars` and `status` directly from the four variables.

You remove `csolve.c` from your project and add the other `.c` files of your mex-function to the S-function.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply again, I have roughly understood your explanation, seems is a big project for me.